# XeLaTeX produces wrong ellipsis

Tags: xetex, typography, kerning

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textellipsis\ /
\ldots\ /
… /
...
\end{document}
```

With pdfLaTeX, I get this result:

[image: Ellipsis (pdflatex)]

While XeLaTeX produces this:

[image]

The kerning is obviously wrong. Now, I understand that XeLaTeX is working with a Unicode glyph here, but I want to turn this replacement off for `\textellipsis` (or `\ldots` for that matter).

To be clear, 95% of the time I'm using pdfLaTeX, so this is not a big problem; I just want to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With XeLaTeX, `\textellipsis` is defined to produce the `…` character U+2026. Since `\ldots` used in text mode is the same as `\textellipsis`, this is the command to be changed.

You can avoid this and also make `…` produce `\ldots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\UndeclareTextCommand{\textellipsis}{TU}

\newunicodechar{…}{\ldots}

\begin{document}

\textellipsis X

\ldots X

…X

...X

\end{document}
```

Using three period in a row is always wrong.

[image]

Comment: I agree, I would never use three periods in a row, I just included that for the sake of comparison.